# Error using 'selu' activation function with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow backend. When I'm trying to use the 'selu' activation function using:

```
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(input_length - 1,)))
model.add(Activation('selu'))
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function:selu
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, Keras can not find any activation function with `'selu'`name. According to the commit history selu activation function was added not so long ago, so I guess that your version of Keras does not have it and updating to the latest one should fix your problem.

Comment: Tried to update keras, anaconda, and tensorflow and they all seem up to date. My keras version is 2.0.5. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selu is not in your `activations.py` of keras (most likely because it was added Jun 14, 2017, only [22 days](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/21cf50734a6996da7023dc500bdcc8ac7d74ef48#diff-2a1c58fc96ce9cf0b88487249b21a319) ago). You can just add the [missing code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py) in the `activations.py` file or create your own `selu` activation in the script.

**Example code**

```
from keras.activations import elu

def selu(x):
    """Scaled Exponential Linear Unit. (Klambauer et al., 2017)
    # Arguments
        x: A tensor or variable to compute the activation function for.
    # References
        - [Self-Normalizing Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02515)
    """
    alpha = 1.6732632423543772848170429916717
    scale = 1.0507009873554804934193349852946
    return scale * elu(x, alpha)

model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(input_length - 1,)), activation=selu)
```

---

NOTE:

With tensorflow 2.0 keras is included. You can get the selu activation with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.activations import selu
```

Comment: That is a nice solution, but I guess, that is valid for your own installed version of `Keras`. Anything that looks like a wrapper function something to create a custom function outside `Keras`'s core?